# non-cyclic example that there is an element not contained in any maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I've just learned today that the analogy of the theorem "every non-unit element in a ring with identity is contained in a maximal ideal" is not true for groups, that is, there are some groups that have some elements not contained in any maximal subgroup. I came up with the obvious example "cyclic groups", in which you can just take the generator element, and it is not contained in any proper subgroup. However, I wondered if there is any non-cyclic example? It must be an infinite group, because I think I managed to show that it's true for all non-cyclic finite groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any proper subgroup of a finite group is contained in a maximal subgroup, because any finite partially ordered set has maximal elements.

So, if $x\in G$ belongs to no maximal ideal and $G$ is finite, we must have that $\langle x\rangle = G$.

On the other hand, the Prüfer group $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ has no maximal subgroup, so no element belongs to a maximal subgroup.

Comment: Oh right, $\mathbb Z_(p^\infty)$ my teacher always talked about this while I played on my phone :(

Comment: @dREaM There weren't smartphones when I followed my course in higher algebra. `;-)`